# SharePoint 2007 Designer conditionally require a field

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create custom form for a SharePoint 2007 document library using SharePoint Designer 2007.  Is it possible to make a form field conditionally required based on the selected item from a drop-down in the the same parent form?

I was able to implement something similar pretty quickly using InfoPath 2007, but my project requirements call for this to be implemented using SharePoint Designer 2007.  I have access to Visual Studio 2010 as well, if not possible in SharePoint Designer 2007, can something like this can be implemented using VS2010?

Comment: You can implement by using `JavaScript`. Please refer this [link][1]. [1]:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/28cae666-6d03-4114-859f-c7ed56c1b795

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer</sup>

> I used [Suren's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66006/sharepoint-2007-designer-conditionally-require-a-field/66051#66051) suggesting to use a JavaScript solution.
>
> After some additional reading I implemented a custom JavaScript driven form validation and submission solution using SPServices jQuery Library. The remaining issue is with assigning correct permissions, for some reason users need to have Managed Lists permission settings in order to properly inject new items in a list using the SPServices library's UpdateListItems function. If I can get that resolved this will complete the solution.